# SQL: count sequentially visits

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following table (visits):

```
id(int) | fb_id(varchar)|   flipbook(varchar) | 
----       ----------         ---------     
1           1123            november 2014
2           1124            november 2014
3           1123            december 2014
4           1124            december 2014
5           1123            december 2014
6           1123            january 2015
7           1126            january 2015
8           1125            february 2015
9           1123            february 2015
10          1124            march 2015
11          1125            march 2015
11          1123            march 2015
```

After the query runs, I want to get the following results:

```
sequence  count
  5         1  (1 user visited 5 flipbooks in a row: 1123)
  2         2  (2 users visited 2 flipbooks in a row: 1124, 1125)
  1         1  (1 user visited only 1 flipbook: 1126)
```

Any ideas how to achieve this?

Comment: What do you mean "in a row"?

Comment: for example if I visited the flipbooks march 2014, april 2014 and june 2014, it means I only visited 2 in a row not 3, because i missed may 2014.

Comment: But you are not counting the 1 visit for 1124 in March.

Comment: No, I am only counting there biggest flipbook sequence.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff Do you think it's impossible to achive this with sql?

Comment: . . Not at all.  Your question simply doesn't explain what "in sequence" really means.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fb_id=1124` visited only 1 flipbook "in a row".  Unless row `id=4` supposed to be "december 20**14**" and not "december 20**15**".

Yes, this is possible to accomplish in MySQL, using user-defined variables. The MySQL Reference Manual cautions that the behavior with this usage of user-defined variables within the same statement is undefined.

```
sequence   count  info
--------  ------  ---------------------------------------------
       5       1  (1 user visited 5 flipbooks in a row: 1123
       2       1  (1 user visited 2 flipbooks in a row: 1125
       1       2  (2 users visited only 1 flipbook: 1124,1126
```

That result set is produced from the following SQL query:

```
SELECT d.seq AS `sequence`
     , COUNT(1) AS `count`
     , CONCAT('('
             ,COUNT(1)
             ,' user'
             ,IF(COUNT(1)>1,'s','')
             ,' visited'
             ,IF(d.seq>1,'',' only')
             ,' '
             ,d.seq
             ,' flipbook'
             ,IF(d.seq>1,'s in a row: ',': ')
             ,GROUP_CONCAT(d.fb_id ORDER BY d.fb_id)
       ) AS `info`
  FROM ( SELECT c.fb_id
              , MAX(c.cnt) AS seq
           FROM ( SELECT @cnt := IF(@prev_fb_id = v.fb_id AND PERIOD_DIFF(v.yyyymm,@prev_yyyymm)=1, @cnt + 1, 1) AS cnt
                       , @prev_yyyymm := v.yyyymm AS yyyymm
                       , @prev_fb_id  := v.fb_id AS fb_id
                    FROM ( SELECT @prev_fb_id := NULL
                                , @prev_yyyymm := NULL
                                , @cnt := 0
                         ) i
                   CROSS
                    JOIN ( SELECT t.fb_id
                                , DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT('01 ',t.flipbook),'%d %M %Y'),'%Y%m') AS yyyymm
                             FROM t
                            GROUP BY t.fb_id, yyyymm 
                            ORDER BY t.fb_id, yyyymm
                          ) v  
                ) c
          GROUP BY c.fb_id
       ) d
 GROUP BY d.seq
 ORDER BY d.seq DESC
```

**FOLLOWUP**

The table name of the source table goes into the query in the innermost inline view, aliased as `v`. (In the example above, the table name is `t`.

To understand how this works, you can run just the query for that innermost inline view, to see what it returns.  It's big job is reformatting the `flipbook` column into a `YYYYMM` format, and ordering the rows. (We will later use the `PERIOD_DIFF` function to calculate the number of months between `flipbook` values.)

The inline view `i` is only there to initialize the user-defined variables we are going to use. We do it in an innermost inline view query so that gets done  before those variables are referenced in the outer query. It's essentially equivalent to running separate SET statements immediately before the query runs. (We don't want any left-over values of the variables mucking with our results.)

Once the `v` and `i` views are materialized (as derived tables), the query in the inline view aliased as `v` can run. (The view queries in the `FROM` clause  essentially serve like tables.)

This query is where the magic is. We're using user-defined variables to preserve the values of the "previous" row, so we can compare that to the current row. If the current row is for the same user, and is exactly one month after the previous row, we increment the sequence count by 1, otherwise, we set it to 1.

Once that query completes, we have a derived table we can use as the row source for yet another query. In this query, we want to find the "maximum" value of that sequence counter for each user. That will give us the longest sequence for each user.

With that set, the outermost query is almost trivial... order by the longest sequence in descending order, and collapse the rows to get a count of the number of users that had the same maximum sequence value.

---

To get the highest number of visits by an `fb_id` within a sequence, we can accumulate the number of visits in that innermost view query.  A `COUNT(1)` or a `SUM(1)` will give us the number of visits in each month.

That can feed into the next query. We can do the same check we do for accumulating the contiguous months. Instead of incrementing by 1, we'll accumulate the total number of visits.

The next query has to be modified. We can't just wrap a `MAX()` around the `tot`, because we wouldn't be guaranteed that the total visits would be from that same longest sequence. We might have 6 visits in a 5 month sequence, but that same user might have visited 8 times in 3 months. So we scrap the MAX() function, and instead use ordering (from highest to lowest). We'll keep the value for the first row for a fb_id, and set the other values to NULL. Then, on the outermost query, we can use `MAX()` aggregate which will ignore the NULLs, and return the highest total visits from among all the users that had the same `sequence` value.

We can get this result:

```
sequence   count  highest_tot
--------  ------  -----------
       5       1            6
       2       1            2
       1       2            1
```

From a query like this:

```
SELECT d.seq AS `sequence`
     , COUNT(1) AS `count`
     , MAX(FLOOR(d.tot)) AS `highest_tot`
  FROM ( SELECT IF(@c_fb_id=c.fb_id,NULL,c.cnt) AS seq
              , IF(@c_fb_id=c.fb_id,NULL,c.tot) AS tot
              , @c_fb_id := c.fb_id AS fb_id
           FROM ( SELECT @cnt := IF(@prev_fb_id = v.fb_id AND PERIOD_DIFF(v.yyyymm,@prev_yyyymm)=1, @cnt + 1, 1) AS cnt
                       , @tot := IF(@prev_fb_id = v.fb_id AND PERIOD_DIFF(v.yyyymm,@prev_yyyymm)=1, @tot + v.tot, v.tot) AS tot
                       , @prev_yyyymm := v.yyyymm AS yyyymm
                       , @prev_fb_id  := v.fb_id AS fb_id
                    FROM ( SELECT @prev_fb_id := NULL
                                , @prev_yyyymm := NULL
                                , @cnt := 0
                                , @tot := 0
                                , @c_fb_id := NULL
                         ) i
                   CROSS
                    JOIN ( SELECT t.fb_id
                                , DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT('01 ',t.flipbook),'%d %M %Y'),'%Y%m') AS yyyymm
                                , SUM(1) AS tot
                             FROM t
                            GROUP BY t.fb_id, yyyymm 
                            ORDER BY t.fb_id, yyyymm
                          ) v  
                ) c
          ORDER BY c.fb_id DESC, c.cnt DESC, c.tot DESC
       ) d
 WHERE d.seq IS NOT NULL
 GROUP BY d.seq
 ORDER BY d.seq DESC
```

Comment: This is amazing, I will test it, but the comments in parentheses were just for explanation purpose.

Comment: Just remove that mess of a third expression from the select list of the outermost query. "`, CONCAT(...) AS info`".

Comment: Stupid question: Where do I put my table name in this query?

Comment: In the inline view aliased as `v`.  The source table name in this query is `t`. You can run just the query for the inline view `v` to see what it returns. The inline view `i` is used to initialize user-defined variables before they are referenced in the outer query, equivalent to running separate `SET` statements before the query runs.  Once you understand what the expression in `v` is doing (formatting "december 2015" to "201512", then you can test the inline view query aliased as `c`. That's where the magic is, comparing the current row to the previous row, to see if it's "in sequence"

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and of course for the code snippet, works great, you are a real sql ninja.

Comment: Ninja: no. Guru: no. Wizard: yes. (You noticed my cone shaped hat is wide-brimmed, tall and pointy. But you may not have noticed my wand.)

Comment: Wizard it is! Do you know how to also get the total visits? for example for sequence 5: we have 6 visits, because user 1123 visited december 2014 flipbook 2 times.

Comment: I added an example query, of one possible way to get the highest "total visits" for each "sequence".

Comment: Thanks, I will check it now, one more small question regarding the first query: If 1 users visits january 2014, march 2014, may 2014 will the sequence 1 have the count 1 or 3?

Comment: The sequence value would be 1, 1, and 1 on each of those rows. The sequence counter only gets incremented if the months are contiguous. When a month is "skipped", the sequence gets reset to 1.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I checked the second query, it doesn't work very well, but I will try to tweak it, thanks again!

Comment: I did some more testing, I think the formula for total visits is correct, but the count is not calculated correctly anymore.

Answer (score 2):

SQL is hard to achieve the result to find out the sequence visits of a user.

However it is easier if you use some other method, eg: create or reuse one of your table :

```
users(fb_id, best_sequence, current_sequence, last_modified)
-------------------------------------------------------
1123         5              3                 2016-01
```

loop over your flipbook eg

```
SELECT * FROM visits WHERE fb_id=1123 AND flipbook >= .... 
(you might redesign data to make SQL easier here)
```

Update current_sequence to 4 if sequence match, or 0 if gap found

If current_sequence > best_sequence, set best_sequence = current_sequence

You can do it via cron job, trigger, or some other methods you feel most comfortable.

This is an idea, and write your own code.

Comment: This is not what I am looking for, for example if I visited the flipbooks march 2014, april 2014 and june 2014, it means I only visited 2 in a row not 3, because i missed may 2014.

Comment: Ah, you mean sequence by month. What will you output this user if he visits on Jan Feb Mar X X  Jun Jul? As there is a gap in between. will you count as 3 or 2 or 3+2?

Comment: For your example it will be 3, because it gets the biggest sequence, also it should work with different years.

Comment: Well, SQL is hard to achieve you might need to try programming language to loop it

Comment: I am using php, any idea how that would look?